# Change value and link depending on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I'm trying to get the text value and the link to change depending on which radio button is selected.  For example, selecting the first radio button would change the text to "Google" and it would link to google.com. While selecting the second radio button would change the text to "bing" and link to bing.com. I have managed to get the text to change, however the link is not working correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/3yrcusv8/

```js
$('.radiogroup').change(function(e){
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $('#amount').val(selectedValue)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup1" class="radiogroup" value="Google" />
    <input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup2" class="radiogroup" value="Bing" />

   
  <input type="submit" name="amount" id="amount" onclick='myFunction()' />
  <script>
    function myFunction() {
   
        if(document.getElementById('radiogroup1').checked) {
            document.getElementById('amount').href = "https://google.com";
        }
    }
    
</script>
```

Comment: You should have a separate `a` element for your link

Comment: Submit should be used with a form, you submit a form, not simply submit an input, but you can also simply redirect the user inside the function, also changing the href of the submit input doesn't make sense, it doesn't take a href attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation

Okay, so rather than having a large if statement, or a large switch statement, you can set a HTML attribute to contain the relevant URL, in my answer, you can see that I've used `data-url`. Personally I find this cleaner for the JavaScript side of things, it also means less logic to be processed within the JavaScript run time too.

Considering with the `change` function, you reference the radio button that has been clicked, you can just access the `data-url` attribute from there, and just update the `a` tag.

Another note, using an `a` tag over a button/input tag makes more sense as an `a` tags purpose is pretty much to be a link on a page, I'd imagine using your original approach may cause some bugs, especially in specific browsers, at least with an `a` tag, you know it'll work.

```js
$('.radiogroup').change(function(e) {
  const $this = $(this), $link = $("#url");
  $link.html($this.val());
  $link.attr("href", $this.attr("data-url"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup1" class="radiogroup" value="Google" data-url="https://google.com" />
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup2" class="radiogroup" value="Bing" data-url="https://www.bing.com/" />

<a id="url" href="" target="_blank">null</a>
```

### Edit

This solution simply uses native JavaScript, nothing else.

```js
const a = document.getElementById("url");
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.radiogroup');

// A simple function to handle the click event for each input.
const clickHandler = i => {
  a.href = i.getAttribute("data-url");
  a.textContent = i.getAttribute("value");
};

// Possibly even less code again. 
inputs.forEach(i => i.onclick = () => clickHandler(i));
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup1" class="radiogroup" value="Google" data-url="https://google.com" />
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup2" class="radiogroup" value="Bing" data-url="https://www.bing.com/" />

<a id="url" href="" target="_blank">null</a>
```

Comment: Would advice to not look for the element in DOM so many times with `$()`. You only need to fetch one reference to the DOM element. Therefore, chaining prototypes and using variables is a better way to go, performance wise.

Comment: If this is a complex or large application, I couldn't agree more, however, considering the size of this specific example, I'm confident that it'll be fine, I'll update the answer for the lols anyway! :) Thanks for the input either way @SølveTornøe

Comment: Haha, you are correct indeed. However, having the mindset of always thinking performance will save you a lot of time in the future. + the code will look a lot cleaner :D

Comment: How do you know the complexity of the application? what if this is just a mock up of the issue they are having? @JO3-W3B-D3V the lol's are great, but using best practice is always better.

Comment: @Art3mix it's just pure assumption, again, that's a fair point, again, I couldn't agree more that best practice is always the way to go! I mean if we're going to get into that level of analysis, then best remove jQuery from the equation, I mean it's not that hard to implement this using only native JavaScript, therefore in this specific example, jQuery is pure bloat?

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V No, because jQuery was tagged, BUT you can add an extra method without jquery, so future users who don't want the jquery solution can find the other one useful. (BTW I would never use the jQuery solution for this even if it is already included on my site)

Comment: @Art3mix he, the only reason I used jQuery is purely because the OP tagged jQuery, personally I no longer use jQuery, like **at all**, I might write a non jQuery solution also.

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V, Same, at my work I need to work with jQuery code (not written by me), so I still need to refresh my jquery skills from time to time, but I won't use it on any of my projects.

Comment: @Art3mix sounds like the same story here ol' chum!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you try to change the href of the submit input, the input doesn't take href as an attribute and it won't do anything if it was changed as well.

Simply redirect the user when they click the button inside the function.

```
function myFunction() {
    if(document.getElementById('radiogroup1').checked) {
        window.location.replace("http://google.com");
    } else {
      window.location.replace("http://bing.com");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom attributes to pass the URL around as below, if you want the user to click the button to open the page.

Google refuses the connection from their end, but you can see from the Bing option that the code works.

```js
// Add click event to radiogroup
$('.radiogroup').change(function(e) {

  // Update url attribute and value of button from radio button
  $('#amount').attr("url", $(this).attr("url")).val($(this).val());
 
});

// Add click event to submit button
$(document).on("click", "#amount", function() {

  // Print URL to console (Can be deleted)
  console.log( $(this).attr("url") );
  
  // Open page in window
  window.location.assign($(this).attr("url"));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup1" class="radiogroup" value="Google" url="http://google.com"/> Google
<input type="radio" name="radiogroup" id="radiogroup2" class="radiogroup" value="Bing" url="http://bing.com" /> Bing (working)


<input type="submit" name="amount" id="amount"  />
```

Answer (score -1):

## We can use a dynamic function to pull this off.

You can simply make a dynamic function in JS that will work for n number of radial buttons by fetching their value attribute and id and change the input button accordingly.

#### The code snippet:

```html
<input id="google" type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="Google" onclick="changeLink(event)" />
<input id="bing" type="radio" name="radiogroup" class="radiogroup" value="Bing" onclick="changeLink(event)" />
<input type="submit" name="amount" id="btn" />
    <script>
      const changeLink = e => {
          let _target = e.currentTarget.id, //get the id name.
              targetValue = document.getElementById(_target).getAttribute('value'), //use id name to fetch value attribute.
              btn = document.getElementById('btn'); //get the btn element from DOM.

        btn.setAttribute('value', targetValue); //set btn elements 'src' attribute to the value of the radial button clicked.
        btn.setAttribute('src', 'https://' + targetValue.toLowerCase() + '.com'); //same src but convert to lower case first.
        
        console.log(btn); //for testing the link
      }
    </script>
```